# “Run-time error ‘-2147023179 (800706b5)” Automation error The interface is unknown

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I recently had an upgrade of my computer and operating system here at work.  I went from Windows XP to Windows 7.
My issue is that I had built several Access 2007 databases which call Excel files and opens them.  Now since the upgrade for whatever reason they do no function.  I get the following error message:

“Run-time error ‘-2147023179 (800706b5)”:
Automation error
The interface is unkown.

Here is an example of the code that I am running:

```
Private Sub cmdOpenXL_Click()
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
With xlApp
    .Visible = True
    Set xlWB = .Workbooks.Open("P:\unitvalu\morningstar\database\output\Nationwide.xlsx", , False)
End With
End Sub
```

I have searched this error message and can't find a solution that seems to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Your Access project includes a reference to the Excel type library, but that reference was broken by the system upgrade.

Open the VB Editor, then choose Tools->References from its main menu.  I suspect you will see "Missing" reported for the "Microsoft Excel Object Library" reference.  If so, uncheck that reference, find the valid reference offered in the drop-down list and place a check mark next to that one.

Click "OK", and then choose Debug->Compile from the VB Editor's main menu.  If the project compiles without error, you're done.  If not, you will have to fix anything the compiler complains about.

Alternatively, you can use late binding which would avoid the need to set an Excel reference.

```vb
Private Sub cmdOpenXL_Click()
Dim xlApp As Object ' Excel.Application
Dim xlWB As Object ' Excel.Workbook
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
With xlApp
    .Visible = True
    Set xlWB = .Workbooks.Open("P:\unitvalu\morningstar\database\output\Nationwide.xlsx", , False)
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply HansUp. I looked at the checked available references and there were none marked "missing". I am fortunate enough to have had my old laptop still and I compared all the references in the old with the new. All references were the same with the exception of file paths for the object libraries.  I did also try your recommendded coding above and I am still getting the same error message at the 4th line of your code. (Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application").  Thank you again for your assistance with this.

Comment: I don't understand how `CreateObject("Excel.Application")` can fail if you have a functional version of Excel installed.  The only other possibility I can think of is your db file is corrupt.  You can test that possibility by creating a new db file and add just that one VBA procedure.  If it works in the new db, that would support the suggestion the old db is corrupt.  But if the VBA procedure still doesn't work in the new db, I'm stumped.  :-(